# Undefined References to boost while making uhd in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boost, uhd

My first attempt to build uhd was to use a script I had written that had worked in the past on two laptops running 14.04. After that, I went back here:

http://files.ettus.com/manual/page_build_guide.html#build_instructions_unix

After that, I went here:

https://kb.ettus.com/Building_and_Installing_the_USRP_Open-Source_Toolchain_(UHD_and_GNU_Radio)_on_Linux

I get the following compile errors. I'm at a loss, as I have install all of libboost, so I'm not sure what is missing. I'm building on the maint branch. I am on a new computer running 16.04.

```
[ 61%] Built target uhd
[ 61%] Linking CXX executable sync_to_gps
CMakeFiles/sync_to_gps.dir/sync_to_gps.cpp.o: In function `_main(int, char**)':
sync_to_gps.cpp:(.text+0x6de): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/sync_to_gps.dir/sync_to_gps.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::string, char>::xparse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&) const':
sync_to_gps.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEE[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEE]+0x1f): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, std::string*, int)'
CMakeFiles/sync_to_gps.dir/sync_to_gps.cpp.o: In function `std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > boost::program_options::to_internal<std::string>(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&)':
sync_to_gps.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options11to_internalISsEESt6vectorISsSaISsEERKS2_IT_SaIS5_EE[_ZN5boost15program_options11to_internalISsEESt6vectorISsSaISsEERKS2_IT_SaIS5_EE]+0x7d): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::to_internal(std::string const&)'
CMakeFiles/sync_to_gps.dir/sync_to_gps.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_parsed_options<char> boost::program_options::parse_command_line<char>(int, char const* const*, boost::program_options::options_description const&, int, boost::function1<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string const&>)':
sync_to_gps.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE[_ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE]+0x15e): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&)'
sync_to_gps.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE[_ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE]+0x1ef): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::set_additional_parser(boost::function1<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string const&>)'
CMakeFiles/sync_to_gps.dir/sync_to_gps.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::string, char>::name() const':
sync_to_gps.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE4nameEv]+0x29): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg'
CMakeFiles/sync_to_gps.dir/sync_to_gps.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool) const'
../lib/libuhd.so.003.010: undefined reference to `boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::load(std::string&)'
../lib/libuhd.so.003.010: undefined reference to `boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >::maybe_assign(boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > > const&)'
../lib/libuhd.so.003.010: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch(boost::filesystem::directory_entry const&, std::string&)'
../lib/libuhd.so.003.010: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
../lib/libuhd.so.003.010: undefined reference to `boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
examples/CMakeFiles/sync_to_gps.dir/build.make:107: recipe for target 'examples/sync_to_gps' failed
make[2]: *** [examples/sync_to_gps] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:393: recipe for target 'examples/CMakeFiles/sync_to_gps.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/sync_to_gps.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which turned out to be an older version of GCC still installed on my Ubuntu system being called. Look at /usr/bin/gcc and /usr/bin/g++ and see if they're linked to /usr/bin/gcc-5 and /usr/bin/g++-5 respectively.

Comment: Yeah, that was it, I got a new computer, put 16.04 on it, but used some scripts I had used from when I was using 14.04 and the 4.9.# compiler. I can't say this message was helpful yet (no points), but it certainly was.